# What is the difference between using django non-rel's djangoappengine and using NDB?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

What is the difference between using Django non-rel's djangoappengine to store data of a Django application, and using the NDB api?

At a conceptual level, are they both at the same level of abstraction? E.g., are they both providing the same convenient methods to store data within Views and Models?

Is one software "lower/higher level" than another?

Why, what circumstances, would you use non-rel over NDB?

Comment: if you are using Django then it just makes sense to use it's ORM. Much of the "magic" django provides is around it's models. So in the circumstance I was using Django I'd use non-rel.

Comment: to expand, if you use NDB with django then you'll have to write the code that converts django models into ndb models (and back again). And that's what non-rel is doing for you! So it's a bit pointless to use NDB directly in django.